# What are the invertible elements of multiplication in the ring $(\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z},+,\cdot)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What are the invertible elements of multiplication in the ring $(\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z},+,\cdot)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? We will have an easier time helping you if we know what is giving you trouble ^_^

Comment: There are only $12$ elements.  Just check one by one if you have to.

Comment: There's only $12$ elements.  But you want to find some $a*b = 1 + 12k$.

Comment: ....  or in other words $ab + 12k = 1$ or more to the point when *CAN'T* you find $ab + 12k = 1$.

Comment: I actually meant Bezout say $ab+12 =1$ is possible when $b$ (and $a$) are relatively prime but not when they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

The $\phi(12)=4$ elements relatively prime to $12$.  Namely, $1,5,7,11$.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is that the elements of $(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)^\times$ are represented by those numbers between $1$ and $n-1$ which are coprime to $n$.

As a corollary, if $n$ is prime, $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ is a field.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is an unorthodox answer using claims that have not been verified by the mathematical community, but I couldn't resist taking the theory 'out for drive' and demonstrate how it doesn't 'fall off a cliff'.

Observe that when using this method we don't need [Euler's totient function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3556728/432081) to get the count for the number of invertibles or identify them by checking for the numbers coprime to $21$. Rather, all the invertibles are 'lurking' in the factorization of larger numbers and are 'discovered' there by a 'combinatorial balancing' algorithm.

---

$\tag 1 1 \times 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$

$\tag 2 11 \times 11 \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$

We will use our $\psi$[-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3556728/432081) to find the remaining invertible elements.

$\quad 11,\quad \psi(11) = 36 \gt 12, \; \lambda(12,11) = 13$
$\quad 10,\quad \psi(10) = 30 \gt 12, \; \lambda(12,10) = 25 = 5 \times 5$
$\quad \;\,9,\quad \psi(9) \;\,= 25 \gt 12, \; \lambda(12,9) \;\,= 37$
$\quad \;\,8,\quad \psi(8) \;\,= 20 \gt 12, \; \lambda(12,8) \;\,= 49 = 7\times 7$
$\quad \;\,7,\quad \psi(7) \;\,= 16 \gt 12, \; \lambda(12,7) \;\,= 61$
$\quad \;\,6,\quad \psi(6) \;\,= 12 \le 12, \; \text{STOP}$

So the set of invertible elements, $J$, is given by

$\quad J = \{\overline1,\overline5,\overline7,\overline{11}\}$

and if $a \in J$ then $a^2 = 1$.

Comment: Well, that wasn't actually what I was going for but.... oh, well.